# Constraints not reflecting on diffrent devices in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, xcode8

I've added vertical and horizontal constraints on my 'Hello World' button but it's not reflecting on other devices. What am I doing wrong ? I've added photos in the links below.

[image: Adding the contraints]

[image: Layout on diffrent devices]

Comment: Please check my answer and reply

Answer (score 0):

Xcode's preview has some bugs, try running the app and i'm sure that you'll get the button centered vertically and horizontally.